# Do ivars have to be enclosed in curly braces?

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables, nsobject

Is it mandatory to enclose instance variables in braces? Or is it just convention?

For example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>    

@interface Person : NSObject
{
    NSString *name;
    int age;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you've written here.  The examples I'm finding on the Internet for the `#import` directive look like this: `#import "Point.h"`
`#import <math.h>`

Comment: You obviously mean `@interface` not `#import`, right?

Comment: Yes, it should be `@interface Person : NSObject {}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to put iVars in "modern" Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566862/where-to-put-ivars-in-modern-objective-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the curly braces are required to declare instance variables. Curly braces right after an @interface or @implementation line mark instance variable declarations. If you omitted the braces, you would simply be declaring global variables.

Answer (score 1):

the curly braces and the enclosed block are used to declare the instance variables of an Objective-C class, and follow a `@interface` or `@implementation` declaration.

You can declare variables outside these blocks, but they will use raw C semantics.
For example, Objective-C has instance and class methods, but it doesn't have a clear concept of *class variable*.
You can still use class variables, with C semantics.

```
static NSMutableArray *myClassList;

@implementation Person
{
    // this block is actually optional
}

// instance methods
// ...

@end
```