# Is it recommended to define ivars for readonly synthesized properties?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, synthesize, ivars

I have come to find that many of the times in which I want to have a synthesized readonly property, I merely implement the getter method of that property in terms of other variables with no need for an ivar, for example (*Note*: I am defining ivars in the interface because I am using OmniGraffle UML software and it does not recognize ivars auto-generated by synthesized properties):

```
@interface Editor : UIView {
    BOOL _wordWrap;
    BOOL _showLineNumbers;
    NSDictionary *_options;
}

@property (nonatomic) BOOL wordWrap;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL showLineNumbers;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSDictionary *options;

@end
```

```
@implementation Editor

@synthesize wordWrap = _wordWrap;
@synthesize showLineNumbers = _showLineNumbers;
@synthesize options = _options;

- (NSDictionary *)options {
    return @{   
                @"WordWrap"         : [NSNumber numberWithBool:self.wordWrap],
                @"ShowLineNumbers"  : [NSNumber numberWithBool:self.showLineNumbers],
            };
}

@end
```

In the above `Editor` class, is it necessary for me to define the `_options` ivar in the header definition and *more* importantly does the auto-generated ivar take up memory or space in the symbol table? Also, would it be more efficient to use `copy`, `retain`, or no value in this case? Just curious.

Comment: why are you defining and synthesizing the ivars explicitly anyway?

Comment: and are you still not using ARC?

Comment: @vikingosegundo I know that the compiler auto-generates the ivars but I am using UML software (OmniGiraffe) and it doesn't seem to be able to handle the ivars made by the synthesized properties. And yes I am using ARC. Is there something in my code that makes it seem like I'm not using ARC??

Comment: "OmniGiraffe" --> "OmniGraffle" ?

Comment: @Martin R Yes that's what I meant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: stop putting your ivar declarations in your `@interface`.  They belong in your `@implementation`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13573236/77567) for a detailed explanation.

Anyway, given what you've written, your `@synthesize options = _options` has no effect.

That `@synthesize` has two possible effects:

1. It adds an instance variable named `_options`, if your class doesn't have one.
2. It generates a getter method, `options`, that returns the value of `_options`, if your class doesn't have a method named `options`.

Since you manually defined the instance variable and the getter, the `@synthesize` does nothing.  You can remove it entirely without changing the meaning of your program.

Specifying `copy` on a readonly property has no effect.  The `copy` and `retain` (or, more properly under ARC, `strong`) attributes only affect the generated setter method, and the compiler doesn't generate a setter for a `readonly` property. (If you change the property to `readwrite` in a class extension, then `copy` matters.)

Yes, the `_options` ivar takes up both memory (for each instance of `Editor`) and space in the symbol table.
Since you're not using the `_options` ivar, you should delete it entirely.  You should also delete the `@synthesize` entirely, so the compiler doesn't generate the `_options` ivar for you.

Comment: I write the ivars because I use OmniGiraffe to generate UML's

Comment: Nevertheless it consumes memory.

Comment: I can still access the property by using self.options right?

Comment: Yes.  When you write `self.options`, it is exactly the same as writing `[self options]`: it sends the `options` message to `self`.

Comment: Okay I followed your advice in the linked answer you posted but when I get into setter methods for text `- (void)setText:(NSString *)text` when calling `self.text = text` I get an error unless I declare `@synthesize text = _text;` instead of `@synthesize text;` before it

Comment: The answer may be different if you are using a `readwrite` property.  Update your question to include the details of your `text` property, how you're trying to use it, and what precise error you're getting.