# Instance variables not nil after instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class called `ContentViewControllerPartial` extending `UIViewController`. I instantiate it several times using 
`content = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContentViewControllerPartial"];` 
expecting to get a new instance each time.

In my class I have an instance variable:

`@implementation ContentViewController
...
AVPlayer* mPlayerAV;`

which is instanciated during viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...
    if ( !mPlayerAV )
    {
       mPlayerAV = [AVPlayer playerWithURL: videoURL];
    }
```

To my surprise, each of my ContentViewControllerPartial classes shared the same instance of mPlayerAV! This was obvious by the fact that it was not nil on the 2nd and 3rd instancations.

Only when I have turned mPlayerAV to a property, I got the expected behaviour - mPlayerAV was no longer shared between instances, and was nil.

What is going on here? How come a private instance variable is shared between instances?

Comment: have you check to see that it have the same address?

Comment: No, but it was not nill and had the same KVO as the original one so I deducted it was the same.

Comment: if you can do a quick check to see if the addresses are the same..dunno if that is the case, but can't hurt

Comment: I agree with @YuviGr, don't deduce, look at the addresses to see if they are in fact the same instance.

Comment: Checked. The same: 0x1736d080

Comment: Also - on the debugger - it does not appear in the list of instance variables.

Comment: I don't see this behavior when I try it. You should show the relevant code for ContentViewControllerPartial, and where you're instantiating new ones.

Comment: You said making it a property fixed it? Was it declared static originally or in the .m file outside the implementation? Sounds like it acted like a static variable. If so each viewDidLoad would reset it to a new AVPlayer but they would all end up the same.

Comment: I had a similar issue. It wasn't in { } like normal instance variables. I believe putting it in the {} fixed the issue for me. However I avoid instance variables and use properties.

Comment: Was not static. Please review my edits. Thanks.

Comment: How are you determining that each of the instances was the same? By logging or with the debugger? Please elaborate on how you're actually doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't put your instance variables in {} it creates a global instead of an instance variable.

The post  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566862/where-to-put-ivars-in-modern-objective-c)  does a great job of do's and don'ts for iVars.

Judging by the code provided I believe this explains the odd behavior. I hope that helps.

Comment: Sillyt me:) This seems to be the answer

Comment: Always glad to help. Like I said I did this before but with a BOOL imagine my confusion and the issues it caused when already set to YES when I expected NO.