# AVPlayerViewController will not dismiss when Notification called

Tags: ios, iphone, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayeritem

## My Code:

```
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strVideo];

    playerController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];

    playerController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];


    playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame;

    playerController.player.currentItem.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTimeMake(timeDuration, 1);

    [playerController.player play];


    playerController.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;


    [self presentViewController:playerController animated:YES completion:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[playerController.player currentItem]];


 - (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification
 {

    [playerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


    NSLog(@"IT REACHED THE END");

  }
```

here the `playerItemDidReachEnd` is called but `avplayercontroller` not dismiss.

Comment: Thanks jigar for editing.....

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove below line of code,

```
playerController.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
```

It may not call your Notification method. Just remove the code and give a try.

Comment: Can you please, add the `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` Notification observer after this line: `playerController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];` and try it?

Comment: Not Working Praveen. Please give another solution for this

Comment: One last try, change `AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone` to `AVPlayerActionAtItemEndAdvance` I have not used this controller till.

Comment: App is crashed with error , reason: 'AVPlayerActionAtItemEndAdvance is not allowed for a player of class AVPlayer'.

Comment: please give another solution or give some example code  for avplayerviewcontroller praveen.

Comment: I've not worked on it. Please wait. If i've got anything. I'll post here.

Comment: Any alternative video player for avplayerviewcontroller for ios 9?

Comment: You can refer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28822645/940096) which is very related to yours.

Comment: Thanks Praveen. I will refer