# Why can't I add objects to this array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

For some reason when I make an NSMutableArray it won't add SKLabelNodes. I add them in my code, but when I ask for the count it gives me 0. Am I doing something wrong? Or is something that should work not working? I honestly have no idea

```
self.titleLabels = [[SKNode alloc]init];
self.titleLabels.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),  700);

self.titleLabelsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:5];

SKLabelNode *label1 = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Code-Pro-Demo"];
label1.text = @"0";
label1.fontSize = 90;
label1.fontColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:90/255.0f green:197/255.0f blue:198/255.0f alpha:1];
label1.position = CGPointMake(-150, 100);
label1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:label1.frame.size];
label1.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

SKLabelNode *label2 = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Code-Pro-Demo"];
label2.text = @"1";
label2.fontSize = 90;
label2.fontColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
label2.position = CGPointMake(-30, 100);
label2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:label2.frame.size];
label2.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

SKLabelNode *label3 = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Code-Pro-Demo"];
label3.text = @"2";
label3.fontSize = 90;
label3.fontColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
label3.position = CGPointMake(150, 100);
label3.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:label3.frame.size];
label3.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

SKLabelNode *label4 = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Code-Pro-Demo"];
label4.text = @"3";
label4.fontSize = 90;
label4.fontColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
label4.position = CGPointMake(-150, 0);
label4.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:label4.frame.size];
label4.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

SKLabelNode *label5 = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Code-Pro-Demo"];
label5.text = @"4";
label5.fontSize = 120;
label5.fontColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:228/255.0f green:70/255.0f blue:38/255.0f alpha:1];
label5.position = CGPointMake(10, -1);
label5.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:label5.frame.size];
label5.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;


[self.titleLabels addChild:label1];
[self.titleLabels addChild:label2];
[self.titleLabels addChild:label3];
[self.titleLabels addChild:label4];
[self.titleLabels addChild:label5];

[self addChild:self.titleLabels];

[self.titleLabelsArray addObject:label1];
[self.titleLabelsArray addObject:label2];
[self.titleLabelsArray addObject:label3];
[self.titleLabelsArray addObject:label4];
[self.titleLabelsArray addObject:label5];
NSLog(@"%i",self.titleLabelsArray.count);
```

Comment: You are using "self" in your array titleLabelsArray and titleLabels. That means you have to make them class properties in your header file. Once you do that everything works fine.

Comment: Yeah, I'd done that already, my answer works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted in your own answer, in this case there is no need to add the 5 SKLabelNode(s) to a distinct array, infact you can iterate them using self.titleLabels.children.

However I tried to understand why your original code does not work as expected, infact your last line of code should indeed print the number 5.

**Step 1**

The compiler does not like this line

```
NSLog(@"%i",self.titleLabelsArray.count);
```

because values of type NSUInteger should not be used as format arguments. Use this instead:

```
NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)self.titleLabelsArray.count);
```

**Step 2**

The code does work properly (and does print 5) **IF the property titleLabelsArray is NOT declared as weak**.
E.g. this is a **correct** declaration:

```
@property NSMutableArray * titleLabelsArray;
```

And this is the output:

```
2015-03-29 16:09:31.919 MyProject[1231:695366] 5
```

On the other hand this is a **wrong** declaration for this case:

```
@property (weak) NSMutableArray * titleLabelsArray;
```

and now you get this output:

```
2015-03-29 16:10:59.713 MyProject[1275:699690] 0
```

So my question: how are you declaring the property titleLabelsArray?

**Step 3**

Finally I would suggest you to use an **instance variable** instead of a property when there is no need to make the variable public.

You can declare it this way

```
@implementation YourSuperCoolClass
{
    NSMutableArray * titleLabelsArray;
}
```

And then you access it without the **self.** prefix:

```
[titleLabelsArray addObject:label1];
[titleLabelsArray addObject:label2];
[titleLabelsArray addObject:label3];
[titleLabelsArray addObject:label4];
[titleLabelsArray addObject:label5];

NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)titleLabelsArray.count);
```

Comment: The advice to use ivars rather than properties needs some justification. With ARC, the difference is largely a matter of style. It's common practice to use properties declared in a class extension so that they're not part of the public interface. Why do you recommend against properties?

Comment: Hello Caleb, you are right. You can achieve encapsulation also with a class extension inside the .m file. Personally I prefer the **@implementation { ... } block** because more essential. The topic has been discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566862/where-to-put-ivars-in-modern-objective-c and there is a very good answer with 75 upvotes that encourages the **@implementation { ... }** approach.

Comment: The question you linked is entirely about *where* to declare ivars, not about choosing between ivars and properties. Before ARC, properties were often preferred even for internal use because they simplified memory management. As I said above, with ARC, the choice is largely a matter of style. But if you're advising someone to use ivars instead of properties, you should provide some justification for that advice.

Comment: Ops my fault! I though the **Option 3** was about properties as well :-) However, my answer to your question is: in this case I prefer instance variables simply because require less code and are more essential.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
self.titleLabels.children
```

It's a built in array for the childnodes

Comment: This doesn't explain why you couldn't add the nodes to an array.