# Access object created by alloc init

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c++

I want to make the following object accessable by all my code functions "public".

```
SomeObj *myobject = [[SomeObj alloc]init];
```

Please note that I have initialized the object inside interface by the following code , but i dose not work

```
Someobj *myobj;
```

But when I use alloc init , its work fine but I dont know how to access the myobj from another function , such as

```
- void runcar() {
       Cars *mycar = [[Cars alloc]init];
       [mycar run];
}
```

My question how I can stop the car from another function ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective-C - Where are class instances declared?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188058/objective-c-where-are-class-instances-declared)

Answer (score -1):

Define it in your interface:

```
@interface Cars ()
@property Cars *mycar;
@end
```

Then initialize it in your init function:

```
@implementation Cars

- (instancetype)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
         _mycar = [[Cars alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Now you can use `_mycar` everywhere within your class. Define it in your header file if you want to use it public.

Comment: Hello thank u , can u tell me what is the (instancetype) , its variable name or method name ???

Comment: Well, it is the type of the instance you created - modern objective c: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html

Comment: "Now you can access `_mycar` **everywhere** within your class" - if you want an instance variable you should declare one, if you want a property you should declare one and access it as `self.mycar` so the getter & setter are used and KVO works, declaring a property but using it as an instance variable is not a good choice.

Comment: Also, I hope you realise this code will lead to a cycle. You're creating a new `Cars` instance within the `Cars` initialiser....